# id values turns always same from foreach in mvc view page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using mvc .net core for a project and I have a view page. I need some id values from this page for using them inside partial view. Because I am using those id values for foreign key in another table to post. From main page these values posts in database correctly. I always post 5 values and always 5 id there in database I saw when I checked. But when I click the accordion this id always turns first id from these 5 values. if I posted as 6,7,8,9,10 it just turns me 6 and it doesn't matter if I clicked the last one in the page or first one. But context and title always correct when I check it from database and from page.

I tried a few jquery code but they didn't work correctly. I need the correct id values when I click other accordions.

I would be glad for any kind of help. Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<match>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

}
<head>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 
    <style>
        .accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

            .active, .accordion:hover {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

        .panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h4>Title List:</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="yzt">
                <td class="xyz" id="item_title" >
                   
                    <button class="accordion" id="title" >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</button>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <p id="modelId" hidden>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Id)</p>
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.context)</p>

                        @await Html.PartialAsync("Create", item.Exams@*, Exams*@)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
        
        //document.querySelectorAll('.accordion').forEach(link => this.addEventListener('click', myFunction))

        //function myFunction() {
        //    document.getElementById("matchId").value = document.getElementById("modelId").innerHTML;
        //    console.log("value is" + document.getElementById("matchId").value);

        //}

        document.querySelectorAll('.panel').forEach(link => this.addEventListener('click', myFunction))

        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("matchId").value = document.getElementById("modelId").innerHTML;
            console.log("value is" + document.getElementById("matchId").value);

        }

        //document.querySelectorAll(".accordion")
        //document.getElementById("match_title").value = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @TinyWang I will for sure. But actually I couldn't take this value from my post method in actionresult. I don't know what is wrong but it comes zero. asp-for and id names same as model and it is code-first. It is working on console also I checked.

Comment: I think you'd better update more code in this question so that we can help you troubleshot it. And you can also create a new question if you want to let more contributers to help on your question because the newest question will get more attention.

Comment: @TinyWang thank you:) I choose your solution worked and applied it. it works on console and it works for first element on list at actionresult. but not for others. I ll push new question. please take a look at new one as well. Many thanks!

Comment: sure, I will : )

Comment: hello @TinyWang nobody replied me yet. can you please take a look when you have time. Thanks!  here is the question
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799621/i-cant-take-matchid-f-k-correctly-in-actionresult-from-a-list-in-partial-vie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to write like this:

```
<div class="panel" id=@item.Id onclick="test(@item.Id)">

function test(val){
    alert(val);
}
```

Your code will create multiple  having id "title" and multiple

having id "modelId", and this is also the reason why you always get the id from the first item, what you write `document.getElementById("modelId").innerHTML` will always get the first dom element which id = "modelId"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! how I couldn't think it really.. I have to work on more dom I guess.